# Is UIWebView KVO compliant?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, key-value-observing

I've set up KVO notification to watch some properties of a UIWebView like so

```
[webView addObserver:self 
          forKeyPath:@"canGoBack"
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
             context:NULL];
```

and have

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
```

but it never gets called. Am I missing something or is UIWebView just not observable?

Comment: The reference docs do not state that UIWebView is KVO compliant, so I would assume that it is not.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I thought might be the case, but I'd seen some people on here suggest it was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`canGoBack` is a `readonly` property: in order for it to be KVO compliant it would have to redeclare that property as `readwrite` in its implementation and then set the property via a synthesised setter. I suspect that instead `canGoBack` is just set via its ivar, which would not send a notification via the KVO system:

```
[self setCanGoBack:YES]; // Would notify KVO observers (as long as any reimplementation of automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey does place restrictions)
_canGoBack = YES; // Would not notify KVO observers
```

This related question discusses the issue in detail: [Is it possible to observe a readonly property of an object in Cocoa Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549672/is-it-possible-to-observe-a-readonly-property-of-an-object-in-cocoa-touch)

As a workaround, you could set a [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) and check the value of `[UIWebView canGoBack]` in `[UIWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:]`.

Comment: While it might be correct that `UIWebView` is not KVO compliant regarding `canGoBack` your explanation is not. It is definitely possible (and common) to implement readonly properties that are observable (see NSOperationQueue's `operations` for example). Observability has nothing to do with readwrite/readonly. The correct answer would have been that nothing is observable unless the documentation explicitly says so.

Comment: Which part of my answer is incorrect? "Observability has nothing to do with readwrite/readonly": agreed, which is why I explain how a property being `readonly` can indirectly affect observability.

Comment: I downvoted because I think your answer is misleading: You do not state the most important fact that observability has to be documented and cannot be somehow deducted from the interface.

Comment: Cool, go ahead and submit your own answer then :)

Comment: Hm, I agree, this is slightly misleading. It's a shame that `canGoBack` is not observable, but it is *not at all* because it's a readonly property.  It's just not observable, the "why" of it is hidden behind UIWebView's implementation.